# image link in message template fails

Tags: message-templates, links, images

Editing a custom message template and am trying to insert an image from the wysiwig editor. Link shows up as:

```
<img alt="logotest" src="http://jgsny.sheridanstreet.net/media/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/black_logo_250_150dpi.png" />
```

I tried editing to

```
<img alt="logotest" src="http://jgsny.sheridanstreet.net/media/civicrm/images/black_logo_250_150dpi.png" /> Still doesn't work.
```

What am I missing?

Thanks, 
Kate

Comment: Does it work if you click on browse server and select the image?

Comment: Assuming you have included the actual image paths in your examples... neither of them work... both get 404 errors.

Answer (score 1):

I guess path (media/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/ ) works fine and you are getting issue with the image in path (media/civicrm/images/black_logo_250_150dpi.png") if this is the case please

check your file permission -

Answer (score 0):

Check your civicrm image url settings

sitename/civicrm/admin/setting/path?reset=1

sitename/civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1

Also check the file folder permission. change ownership of file folder to www-data:www-data and permission should be 755.